# escaping string on Windows command line

Tags: windows, winapi, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass string to Win32 program from command line so it will be printed without changes.

Why I have to escape
**"AAA <BBB@pobox.com>"** as **"""AAA <BBB@pobox.com>"""**
but
**"AAA <BBB@pobox.com>",** (comma included) as **"\"AAA ^<BBB@pobox.com^>\","**

I see no consistency in escaping rules for windows command line

P.S. I'm trying to generate a .cmd file

Update:

I'm using simple C program for testing that is compiled with gcc, no additional object files linked. If I replace it with perl, rules remain same.

I'm trying to create a general escaping algorithm. It will generate .cmd file which will call perl with output redirect. Currently I have a problem that if string contains odd number of double quotes which are escaped with backslash, output redirect does not function. Same problem is described in the last comment to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/17/10063629.aspx .

If I use "" as escape for ", it splits on space, so it will result it 2 parameters instead of one. Also "" has some artifacts.

Comment: What command interpreter are you using? Argument splitting is a function of it, not Windows itself.

Comment: I dont even understand your requirement. To the best of my knowledge, the first line in bold, is VB's way of escaping quotes, and the second line is C's(and other similar languages) way of doing the same. And if this is what you are talking about, its really not the windows OS, but the languages' own syntax. BTW, can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I think to get a good answer you need to be more specific with the environment. Are you talking about escaping for the command interpreter, or the argument parsing for a specific app?

Comment: As I need to pass <> to program, I need escaping for command interpreter too, but in general to a program (which possibly uses CommandLineToArgvW under the hood).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, we can probably assume he’s using `cmd` which does no argument splitting before passing `CommandLine`.

Answer (score 7):

In windows there is no one way of getting a command line and parsing it.  Mostly programs have generally been left to deal with that themselves.

There is a recent post by Raymond Chen about the `CommandLineToArgvW` function which mentions various rules about quoting but they'll only apply if the program uses that particular function. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/17/10063629.aspx

In windows the command line is passed to the program unmolested (i.e. no wildcards expanded) and then the program needs to deal with it.  The programming language may provide a convenience which does some default argument parsing, and this might use a standard windows function like [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) but even so the program could opt to read the unadulterated string itself thereby skipping those standards.

This means you need to figure out the rules for the particular program you are trying to script yourself and then use them.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but thought I'd point out that VC++ at least provides a way of automatically expanding wildcards, by linking setargv.obj or wsetargv.obj into your application.

Comment: There is nothing about wildcards in my question. A simple program compiled in MSVC without any additional calls or libraries still understands "" \" and ^.

Comment: The general point was that a program should be provided with exactly what was passed to you on the command line.  The language you use may provide some extra processing (and that might use a library from Microsoft) to fill in argv and argc for example but fundamentally it's not not something that windows does for you.  Therefore I don't think there is a single rule that works for every single program on windows.  Having said that there are common rules followed by a lot of programs.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried those as parameters into one of my own programs, and both versions (with or without the comma) can be escaped in both ways (using either `"""` or `\"` to escape the quotes). The only reason I can see that the `<` and `>` need to be escaped with `^` in the second version is that as the command line is seeing them as I/O redirections prior to passing them to the application, due to the different way of escaping the string quotes.

Comment: So you’re using something like `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute()`. If the OP needs to escape `<` or `>`, looks like the OP is calling `cmd` either directly or through something like `ShellExecute()`.